# Calculating Average by Using a Function

Tags: swift, average

I am trying to write a function to calculate the average in a simple math app.  I am not getting any errors at all, but the code output is not showing up in the right sidebar in my Xcode playground.  It outputs the two zeros in my code and stops there.  Any thoughts on what's wrong?

```
func averageOf(numbers: Int...) -> Float {
    var sum = 0
    var numberTotal = 0

    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
        numberTotal = numbers.count
    }

    return Float(sum / numberTotal)
}

averageOf()
averageOf(10, 56, 75, 90, 109)
```

Comment: Divide-by-zero error?

Comment: Note also that you should return `Float(sum)/Float(numberTotal)`, otherwise you have an integer division and the result is truncated, e.g. averageOf(1, 2) gives 1 instead of 1.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `averageOf()`, it seems to cause the playground to crash (division by zero, because `numberTotal` is `0`). 
For instance, if you called it like this:

```
averageOf(10, 56, 75, 90, 109)
averageOf(10, 20, 30)
averageOf()
averageOf(10, 20, 30)
```

you would get an output for the first two calls, but not for the second two.

**UPDATE 3** (credits to @wumm)
If you clicked on any of variables on the right panels or opened an assistant editor , you would see the error (rather strange one, though):

```
Playground execution failed: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
* thread #1: tid = 0x1c4a02, 0x000000010aff7e14, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x000000010aff7e14
```

The solution is to check numberTotal in the end. And, by the way, there is no need to assign it inside the loop :)
Here is a fixed version:

**UPDATE:** cheching numberTotal in the beginning is more reasonable indeed (credits to @kovpas):
**UPDATE 2:** changed the `return` part. Credits to `@MartinR.

```
func averageOf(numbers: Int...) -> Float {
    var numberTotal = numbers.count
    if numberTotal == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    var sum = 0

    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }
    return Float(sum)/Float(numberTotal)
}

averageOf(10, 56, 75, 90, 109)
averageOf(10, 20, 30)
averageOf()
averageOf(10, 20, 30)
```

Comment: There is a error, even a quite strange one: `Playground execution failed: error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
* thread #1: tid = 0x1b63f, 0x00000001075beb38, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x00000001075beb38`

Comment: @wumm, I'm not very familiar with the playground yet. Where is it displayed? My playground just doesn't output anything. I tried to show the console, but there's nothing there either.

Comment: @wumm [that's what I see](http://s16.postimg.org/ubqh1s7hx/Screen_Shot_2014_06_15_at_2_32_32.png) (png, ~170 kb)

Comment: @wumm, Found it, sorry for bothering you.

Comment: That's okay. I just wonder how you opened that side bar/panel. I always do by clicking on any of the values on the right side. Did you found another way (my seems not to be the best)?

Comment: @wumm, updated my answer, thank you for your help :) It turns out that this panel is in essence an assistant editor :) Actually, the Timeline icon in the right panel's header is the assistant editor icon. So you can open it with Alt(Option)+Cmd+Enter.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, except as a learning exercise, `averageOf()` is best implemented reusing existing functionality as:

```
func averageOf(_ head: Int, rest: Int...) -> Double {
  return Double (rest.reduce (head, combine: +)) / Double (1 + rest.count)
}
27> averageOf (1, 2, 3)
$R6: Double = 2
```

The above avoids the 'how do you average no numbers' problem by requiring one argument.  You also will want to be careful about your division use:

```
 33> Double (3/2)
$R9: Double = 1
 34> Double(3)/Double(2)
$R10: Double = 1.5
```

Also, the usefulness of optional arguments created with `...` is limited until there is an `apply()` function like

```
   var theAverage = apply (averageOf, someGiantArrayOfInts)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first check if your array contains numbers. Otherwise you divide by 0.

```
func averageOf(numbers: Int...) -> Float {
    if numbers.count == 0 {
        return 0
    }

    var sum = 0

    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
    }

    return Float(sum / numbers.count)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func average(numbers: Int...) -> Float {

    var sum = 0
    var numberTotal = 0
    
    for number in numbers {
        sum += number
        numberTotal = numbers.count
    }
    return Float(sum) / Float(numberTotal)
}


average(numbers: 5, 5, 5)
```

// this seemed to have worked

Comment: Thanks for contributing. Please note, though this may solve the problem, your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on [how to write good answers in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).